# SQL-Query to get nested JSON Array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data in a MS-SQL database:
(Microsoft SQL Server Standard Version 13; Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18)

```
+----------+-----------+-----+--------+---------+---------+
| LastName | Firstname | Age | Weight | Sallery | Married |
+----------+-----------+-----+--------+---------+---------+
| Smith    | Stan      |  58 |     87 |  59.000 | true    |
| Smith    | Maria     |  53 |     57 |  45.000 | true    |
| Brown    | Chris     |  48 |     77 | 159.000 | true    |
| Brown    | Stepahnie |  39 |     67 |  95.000 | true    |
| Brown    | Angela    |  12 |     37 |     0.0 | false   |
+----------+-----------+-----+--------+---------+---------+
```

I want to get a nested JSON array from it that looks like this:

```
 [
        {
            "Smith": [
                {
                    "Stan": [
                        {
                            "Age": 58,
                            "Weight": 87,
                            "Sallery": 59.000,
                            "Married": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "Maria": [
                        {
                            "Age": 53,
                            "Weight": 57,
                            "Sallery": 45.000,
                            "Married": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Brown": [
                {
                    "Chris": [
                        {
                            "Age": 48,
                            "Weight": 77,
                            "Sallery": 159.000,
                            "Married": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "Stepahnie": [
                        {
                            "Age": 39,
                            "Weight": 67,
                            "Sallery": 95.000,
                            "Married": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "Angela": [
                        {
                            "Age": 12,
                            "Weight": 37,
                            "Sallery": 0.0,
                            "Married": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

How do I have to build the SQL query?

I have tried different ways but I don't get to dynamize the root or the root keeps repeating itself....

For example, I tried the following query:

I get one Level with:

```
WITH cte AS
(
       SELECT FirstName
              js = json_query(
              (
                     SELECT Age,
                            Weight,
                            Sallery,
                Married
                             FOR json path,
                            without_array_wrapper ) )
       FROM   Table1)
SELECT '[' + stuff(
       (
                SELECT   '},{"' + FirstName + '":' + '[' + js + ']'
                FROM     cte
                 FOR xml path ('')), 1, 2, '') + '}]'
```

But I need one more nested level with LastName

Another try:

```
SELECT
  LastName ,json  
FROM Table1 as a
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT
    FirstName
  FROM Table1 as b
  WHERE a.LastName = b.LastName
  FOR JSON PATH
) child(json)
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: Which sql platform your are using?

Comment: Server = Microsoft SQL Server Standard Version 13

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: SELECT
  LastName ,json  
FROM Table1 as a
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT
    FirstName
  FROM Table1 as b
  WHERE a.LastName = b.LastName
  FOR JSON PATH
) child(json)
FOR JSON PATH

Comment: That would not be a real-world JSON presentation. Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, it's not a homework assignment. The data are in fact different... But the scheme is identical. The structure of the JSON array is needed this way, because the data is processed further in an existing program using JSON.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `JSON_AGG` nor `JSON_OBJECT_AGG`, which would have helped here. But we can hack it with `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`

```sql
WITH ByFirstName AS
(
    SELECT
      p.LastName,
      p.FirstName,
      json = STRING_AGG(j.json, ',')
    FROM Person p
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          p.Age,
          p.Weight,
          p.Sallery,
          p.Married
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) AS j(json)
    GROUP BY
      p.LastName,
      p.FirstName
),
ByLastName AS
(
    SELECT
      p.LastName,
      json = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        '"',
        STRING_ESCAPE(p.FirstName, 'json'),
        '":[',
        p.json,
        ']'
      ), ',')
    FROM ByFirstName p
    GROUP BY
      p.LastName
)
SELECT '[{' +
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        '"',
        STRING_ESCAPE(p.LastName, 'json'),
        '":{',
        p.json,
        '}'
  ), ',') + '}]'
FROM ByLastName p
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16f26def5c484e4ecce2cdc4b5922d61)

This gets you

```json
[
  {
    "Brown": {
      "Angela": [
        {
          "Age": 12,
          "Weight": 37,
          "Sallery": 0,
          "Married": false
        }
      ],
      "Chris": [
        {
          "Age": 48,
          "Weight": 77,
          "Sallery": 159000,
          "Married": true
        }
      ],
      "Stepahnie": [
        {
          "Age": 39,
          "Weight": 67,
          "Sallery": 95000,
          "Married": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "Smith": {
      "Maria": [
        {
          "Age": 53,
          "Weight": 57,
          "Sallery": 45000,
          "Married": true
        }
      ],
      "Stan": [
        {
          "Age": 58,
          "Weight": 87,
          "Sallery": 59000,
          "Married": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It looks good and could be the solution. but unfortunately SQL SERVER 2013 does not know STRING_AGG function yet. I think I can substitute it with stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to get your desired JSON output but, as you can see below, the code is rather convoluted...

```sql
/*
 * Data setup...
 */
create table dbo.Person (
  LastName varchar(10),
  FirstName varchar(10),
  Age int,
  Weight int,
  Sallery int,
  Married bit
);

insert dbo.Person (LastName, FirstName, Age, Weight, Sallery, Married)
values
  ('Smith', 'Stan', 58, 87, 59000, 1),
  ('Smith', 'Maria', 53, 57, 45000, 1),
  ('Brown', 'Chris', 48, 77, 159000, 1),
  ('Brown', 'Stepahnie', 39, 67, 95000, 1),
  ('Brown', 'Angela', 12, 37, 0, 0);

/*
 * Example JSON query...
 */
with Persons as (
  select LastName, Stan, Maria, Chris, Stepahnie, Angela
  from (
    select
      LastName,
      FirstName,
      (
        select Age, Weight, Sallery, Married
        for json path
      ) as data
    from dbo.Person
  ) src
  pivot (max(data) for FirstName in (Stan, Maria, Chris, Stepahnie, Angela)) pvt
)
select
  json_query((
    select
      json_query(Stan) as Stan,
      json_query(Maria) as Maria
    from Persons
    where LastName = 'Smith'
    for json path
  )) as Smith,
  json_query((
    select
      json_query(Chris) as Chris,
      json_query(Stepahnie) as Stepahnie,
      json_query(Angela) as Angela
    from Persons
    where LastName = 'Brown'
    for json path
  )) as Brown
for json path;
```

Which yields the output...

```json
[
    {
        "Smith": [
            {
                "Stan": [
                    {
                        "Age": 58,
                        "Weight": 87,
                        "Sallery": 59000,
                        "Married": true
                    }
                ],
                "Maria": [
                    {
                        "Age": 53,
                        "Weight": 57,
                        "Sallery": 45000,
                        "Married": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Brown": [
            {
                "Chris": [
                    {
                        "Age": 48,
                        "Weight": 77,
                        "Sallery": 159000,
                        "Married": true
                    }
                ],
                "Stepahnie": [
                    {
                        "Age": 39,
                        "Weight": 67,
                        "Sallery": 95000,
                        "Married": true
                    }
                ],
                "Angela": [
                    {
                        "Age": 12,
                        "Weight": 37,
                        "Sallery": 0,
                        "Married": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, I forgot to say that in reality the table has several thousand data. This means that the ROOT must be dynamic.

Comment: I get one Level with:

WITH cte AS
(
       SELECT FirstName
              js = json_query(
              (
                     SELECT Age,
                            Weight,
                            Sallery,
                Married
                             FOR json path,
                            without_array_wrapper ) )
       FROM   Table1)
SELECT '[' + stuff(
       (
                SELECT   '},{"' + FirstName + '":' + '[' + js + ']'
                FROM     cte
                 FOR xml path ('')), 1, 2, '') + '}]'